# Why does injecting the sanity client in a nestjs service provider result in a "TypeError: client_1.default is not a function"?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, typeerror, nestjs, sanity

Creating a service provider in [nestjs](https://nestjs.com/) and importing a [sanity client](https://www.sanity.io/docs/js-client):

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import sanityClient, { SanityClient } from '@sanity/client';

@Injectable()
export class SanityService {
  public readonly client: SanityClient = sanityClient({
    projectId: '******',
    dataset: '********',
    apiVersion: '2021-08-18',
    token: '*******',
    useCdn: false,
  });
}
```

Results in:

```
[Nest] 53293  - 08/18/2021, 2:05:07 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] client_1.default is not a function
TypeError: client_1.default is not a function
    at new SanityService (/**/src/sanity/sanity.service.ts:6:54)
    at Injector.instantiateClass (/**/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:291:19)
    at callback (/**/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:43:41)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/**/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:119:24)
    at Injector.loadInstance (/**/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:47:9)
    at Injector.loadProvider (/**/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:69:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 4)
    at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (/**/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:44:9)
    at /**/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:29:13
    at async Promise.all (index 2)
```

My tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: try adding `"esModuleInterop": true` in your tsconfig

Comment: Thank you - that hit the spot :)

Comment: @MicaelLevi that forces me to do several changes in files, is there another way?

Comment: @AlbertoLeón use `import * as foo from 'bar'` or `import foo from 'bar'`, not sure which one will solve your issue

Comment: I finally needed to update all the imports to make the esModuleInterop work.