# How to query Sanity client with NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, sanity

Right now I have React app initialized with Vite connected with Sanity.
Everything is working just fine, Sanity client is connected, React is fetching data from Sanity, I'm receiving it with no problem.
[image]

But the problem is, that if I deploy React app with Sanity connected, then I will leak my `projectID` and `sanity_token` to the fronted, which I want to avoid of course.

So I have to make some backend REST API which will be fetched by React, and then my API will fetch Sanity. I could do it with Node.js and Express without problem, but I decided that I will use NestJS and learn something instead.

[image]

But when it comes to NestJS, everything is connected a bit different.

On the front I had :

```js
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';

export const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_SANITY_PROJECT_ID, 
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2022-02-01', 
  useCdn: true,
  token: import.meta.env.VITE_SANITY_TOKEN
});
```

And for NestJS I found something like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import sanityClient, { SanityClient } from '@sanity/client';

@Injectable()
export class SanityService {
  public readonly client: SanityClient = sanityClient({
    projectId: process.env.SANITY_PROJECT_ID, 
    dataset: 'production',
    apiVersion: '2022-02-01', 
    useCdn: true,
    token: process.env.SANITY_TOKEN
  });
}
```

My question is that if it's a good way to connect Sanity client?
How to query Sanity client with specified GROQ query?

Till now I was using this on the frontend, but it's not gonna work in NestJS:

```js
const query = '*[_type == "blogPost"]';

    client.fetch(query)
      .then((data) => {
        setPosts(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this is the proper way to connect with Sanity client, I had an issue with that similar to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68832152/why-does-injecting-the-sanity-client-in-a-nestjs-service-provider-result-in-a-t)

And the solution was the same as in the thread above. Add `"esModuleInterop": true` to tsconfig.json.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

Then call for data to sanity client is working properly:

```js
  @Get()
  async getAllPosts() {
    
    // initialize sanity instance
    const sanityService = new SanityService();

    // your query
    const query = '*[_type == "blogPost"]';

    try {
      const data = await sanityService.client.fetch(query);
      
      return data;

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.msg);
    }
  }
```